# How to speed up an asp.net page that uses jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance, webforms, pagespeed

I have a webpage that allows the user to input information into a form.  I am using some jQuery on the page as well as in the code behind, and I need to find a way to speed up the page (taking about 30 seconds to load).  I am sure there are some pretty easy fixes to speed up the loading of the website, below are some snippits of the site.  Any help would be great on speeding up the loading of the site.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          var i = $("table.newRequirementClass tr td:contains('Description')").next();

          i.textLimiter({
              maxLength: 255,
              elCount: 'elCount'
          });
          $("#submitMIFields").hide();
          $("#submitMIFields").toggle(false);
          $("[id$='chkMI']").change(function () {
              $("#submitMIFields").toggle("slow");
          });

          $(".MIHead").hide();
      });

      function Count(text, maxLength) {
          if (text.value.length > maxLength) {
              text.value = text.value.substring(0, maxLength);
          }
      }
   </script>
```

```
<div style="text-align: left; width: 80%;">
        <h2 runat="server" id="h2Caption">New Requirement</h2>
        <asp:Panel ID="ErrorSummary" runat="server">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblErrors" />
        <asp:ValidationSummary id="valSummary" runat="server"
        HeaderText="Please Revise The Following Errors:"
        ShowSummary="true" DisplayMode="List" />

        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="dvNewRequirement" 
            runat="server"  CssClass="newRequirementClass"
            AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            Width="100%"
            DefaultMode="Insert"
            SkinID="SampleDetailsView" 
            CssSelectorClass="PrettyDetailsView" 
            OnItemInserting="dvNewRequirement_ItemInserting" 
            OnModeChanging="dvNewRequirement_ModeChanging" 
            ondatabound="dvNewRequirement_DataBound" >
            <FieldHeaderStyle Width="15em" Font-Bold="True"/>
            <Fields>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" Text="Pre-Solicitation" runat="server" />

                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vehicle:" Visible="false" >
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVehicles"
                            runat="server" 
                            DataTextField="strDescription" 
                            DataValueField="strCode" 
                            DataSource='<%# CodeLists.Vehicles() %>'
                            AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Office:">
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <Proj:OrgTree id="OrgTree" runat="server" Filter="false" Visible='<%# (AuthenticatedUser.CanCreateMis() != true) ? true : false %>'
                        SelectedValue = '<%# (AuthenticatedUser.IsCUS() != true) ? BaseControl.LoginOffice : Guid.Empty %>' />
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Office:">
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <Proj:OrgTree id="customerOrgTree" Filter="false" runat="server"
                        SelectedValue = '<%# (AuthenticatedUser.CanCreateMis() == true) ? BaseControl.LoginOffice : Guid.Empty %>' />
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description:" ControlStyle-CssClass="Description">
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDescription"
                            TextMode="multiLine" onKeyUp="Count(this,257)" onChnage="Count(this,257)"
                            Width="90%"/><br />
                            <div id="elCount"></div>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Procurement Type:">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProcurementTypeList" 
                            runat="server" 
                            DataTextField="strDescription" 
                            DataValueField="strCode" 
                            DataSource='<%# CodeLists.ProcurementTypes() %>'
                            AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type:">
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypeList" 
                            runat="server" 
                            DataTextField="strDescription" 
                            DataValueField="strCode" 
                            DataSource='<%# CodeLists.Types() %>'
                            AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>

                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Est Total Value:">
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEstValue" 
                        runat="server"  />
                    <ajax:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1"
                        TargetControlID="txtEstValue"
                        FilterType="Numbers,Custom"
                        ValidChars=",."
                        runat="server" />                                                    
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Contact Date:">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerContact" 
                        runat="server"  />
                    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="calCustomerContact" 
                        runat="server" 
                        TargetControlID="txtCustomerContact" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Req Start Date:">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtReqStartDate" 
                        runat="server" />
                    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="calReqStartDate" 
                        runat="server" 
                        TargetControlID="txtReqStartDate" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Previous Number:">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAwardList" 
                        runat="server" 
                        DataTextField="strAwardNumber" 
                        DataValueField="strAwardNumber" 
                        DataSource='<%# CodeLists.AwardNumbers() %>'
                        AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="None" Value="" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Currency">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurrencyList"
                        runat="server"
                        DataTextField="strCultureName"
                        DataValueField="strCulture"
                        DataSource='<%# CodeLists.Currency() %>'
                        AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="?">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkMI" />
                    <div id="submitMIFields">
                        <Proj:MI runat="server" ID="initialMI" />
                    </div>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField InsertText="Submit" ShowCancelButton="False" 
                    ShowInsertButton="True" ControlStyle-CssClass="NewReqSubButton" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>

    </div>


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (AuthenticatedUser.CanCreateMis())
    {
        CheckBox chkMI = (CheckBox)dvNewRequirement.FindControl("chkMI");
        chkMI.Checked = true;
        chkMI.Enabled = false;
        runjQueryCode();

    }
}

    private string getJQueryCode()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function() {");
    sb.AppendLine("$('#submitMIFields').show();");
    sb.AppendLine(" });");

    return sb.ToString();

}

private void runjQueryCode()
{
    ScriptManager requestSM = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
    if (requestSM != null && requestSM.IsInAsyncPostBack)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,
                                                typeof(Page),
                                                Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                                getJQueryCode(),
                                                true);
    }
    else
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page),
                                                Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                                getJQueryCode(),
                                                true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific bottleneck?  If the browser is waiting for the server to respond, profile the server-side code and see what's taking it so long (which method calls, etc.).  If the browser is doing a lot of work, something like FireBug can be used to see what's taking so long (loading resources, running scripts, etc.).  Where's your biggest performance bottleneck?

Comment: @David I am not sure where the bottle neck is.  The page loads up (the loading bar is 100%) but it sits at a blank page for about 30 seconds before the page displays

Comment: This is just nitpicking and is not the cause of any performance issue, but your use of StringBuilder in your getJQueryCode method is unnecessary. String concatenation would be better (the compiler will do it all at compile time, but even at runtime it would be better, because you only have a few items to concatenate).  In this case, it looks like you might be doing this in order to include newline characters in the javascript code. The best option would probably be to use a [multi-line string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287596(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice I will look into that once I figure out the speed issue, but thanks for the info!

Comment: The first thing I'd do is comment out the whole $(document).ready block, just to ascertain whether it's the asp or javascript that's causing the issue.

Comment: @Archer I commented it out and there was no noticeable change in the speed

Comment: Okay, so you're no closer to solving it, but you know the problem lies in the asp, not the javascript.  I'm guessing it's getting a lot of data and the page is rather heavy when it's returned?  If so, maybe consider returning empty controls and using Ajax to get the data.

Comment: @Archer do you have any examples of doing that?

Comment: Does it load slowly even for the 2nd time? First time 30sec loading can happen because the server is just compiling the page at first request.

Answer (score 0):

> I am sure there are some pretty easy fixes to speed up the loading of the website

that really depends, being this is using webforms performance improvements usually require alot of work. Webforms is one of the most difficult web frameworks to debug and extend.

Typically performance improvements can be made by

1. improving the query plan
2. reduce remote calls (IO, DB, etc)
3. reducing the amount of data loaded.

viewstate is the #1 performance killer with webforms. anything you can do to reduce the size of viewstate is a good thing.

if you are only displaying a few records at a time, then only load the records you want to display. page through the data at the database, not the UI. when you load 100s or 1000s of records from the db and then display 1-20 records all the records retrieved are stored in viewstate, not just the records displayed to the user.

the number of queries executed can also decrease performance. say you have a gridview and when you bind to the gridview you load a list of lookup values into a dropdown using a datasource control. each time the dropdown list is bound the datasource will execute. it's very easy to create a *select n+1* issue like this.

finally, if the query is poorly formed, or the db schema is not optimized (indexing, etc) queries can take seconds or even minutes rather than milliseconds to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Dig out a copy of Dynatrace AJAX edition (http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/)

How big is the viewstate, and how long is that de-serialisation of it taking?

How many of the form fields rely on data that's in the viewstate and how big are the dropdown lists etc.

My guess is that you're pushing too much data that then has to be de-serialised and populated into the form via Javascript.

Also what browser are you using and is it any faster with current Chrome or Firefox build?

Comment: I will look into that, thanks!  I am forced to use IE, everyone is required to use it and this is an intranet system

Comment: OK, but even if you are forced to use IE for corporate reasons... Can you try it in a recent Chrome / Firefox version to compare performance?